# Match words that consist of specific characters, excluding between special brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I'm trying to match **words that consist only of characters in this character class**: `[A-z'\\/%]`, *excluding* cases where:

- they are between `<` and `>`
- they are between `[` and `]`
- they are between `{` and `}`

So, say I've got this funny string:

```
[beginning]<start>How's {the} /weather (\\today%?)[end]
```

I need to match the following strings:

```
[ "How's", "/weather", "\\today%" ]
```

**I've tried using this pattern:**

```regex
/[A-z'/\\%]*(?![^{]*})(?![^\[]*\])(?![^<]*>)/gm
```

But for some reason, it matches:

```
[ "[beginning]", "", "How's", "", "", "", "/weather", "", "", "\\today%", "", "", "[end]", "" ]
```

I'm not sure why my pattern allows stuff between `[` and `]`, since I used `(?![^\[]*\])`, and a similar approach seems to work for **not** matching `{these cases}` and `<these cases>`. I'm also not sure why it matches all the empty strings.

Any wisdom? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are essentially two problems with your pattern:

1. Never use `A-z` in a character class if you intend to match only letters (because it will match more than just letters<sup>1</sup>). Instead, use `a-zA-Z` (or `A-Za-z`).
2. Using the `*` quantifier after the character class will allow empty matches. Use the `+` quantifier instead.

So, the fixed pattern should be:

```regex
[A-Za-z'/\\%]+(?![^{]*})(?![^\[]*\])(?![^<]*>)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SUP5f6/1)**.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>The `[A-z]` character class means *"match any character with an ASCII code between 65 and 122"*. The problem with that is that codes between 91 and 95 are *not* letters (and that's why the original pattern matches characters like '[' and ']').</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Split it with regular expression:

```js
let data = "[beginning]<start>How's {the} /weather (\\today%?)[end]";
let matches = data.split(/\s*(?:<[^>]+>|\[[^\]]+\]|\{[^\}]+\}|[()])\s*/);

console.log(matches.filter(v => "" !== v));
```

Comment: So, I took the liberty of making your code into a snippet using the users string, and I don't think it quite works-- see what is output.  Unless I missed something

Comment: Updated the results by filtering out empty string.

Comment: Note that this will include characters other than the ones that the OP wanted to match. For example, it currently includes the `?` in `\\today%?`.

Answer (score 1):

You can match all the cases that you don't want using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and place the character class in a capturing group to capture what you want to keep.

The `[^` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any character except what is specified.

```
(?:\[[^\][]*]|<[^<>]*>|{[^{}]*})|([A-Za-z'/\\%]+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[[^\][]*]` Match from opening till closing `[]`
  - `|` Or
  - `<[^<>]*>` Match from opening till closing `<>`
  - `|` Or
  - `{[^{}]*}` Match from opening till closing `{}`
- `)` Close non capture group
- `|` Or
- `([A-Za-z'/\\%]+)` Repeat the character class 1+ times to prevent empty matches and capture in **group 1**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/amkD2m/1)

```js
const regex = /(?:\[[^\][]*]|<[^<>]*>|{[^{}]*})|([A-Za-z'/\\%]+)/g;
const str = `[beginning]<start>How's {the} /weather (\\\\today%?)[end]`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[1] !== undefined) console.log(m[1]);
}
```